# How to iterate through a list with a Nonetype attribute? (Python)

Tags: python, network-programming, iteration, ping

I'm making a script for LAN host discovery in Python(without scapy yea I know, trying to use the sockets library for a learning experience). I am able to discover hosts but am having trouble separating the live hosts from the ones that returned no response because the only indicator I have is the timeout response(ping, which is either a float or None), but I cannot iterate ping as it can be a nontytpe so I tried to use hasattr to check the hosts, but I get a empty dictionary. Is there a better way I can iterate through the hosts? I can make the list of hosts a dictionary, but that doesn't solve the problem of iterating through nonetypes. Any input is appreciated, thanks.

```
`if __name__ == '__main__':
live = []
livee = []
for host, ping in multi_ping_query(subnet).iteritems():
    subnet = host, '=', ping
    print(subnet)
    live.append(subnet)
for ping in live:
    check = hasattr(ping, 'Nonetype')
    if check == False:
        livee.append(host)
print(livee)
```

Here is the function for multi_ping_query, I tried tweaking it to return a string if it does not connect however I didn't have much success with that either.

```
def multi_ping_query(hosts, timeout=1, step=512, ignore_errors=False):
results, host_list, id = {}, [], 0
for host in hosts:
    try:
        host_list.append(socket.gethostbyname(host))
    except socket.gaierror:
        results[host] = None
while host_list:
    sock_list = []
    for ip in host_list[:step]: # select supports only a max of 512
        id += 1
        sock_list.append(PingQuery(ip, id, timeout))
        host_list.remove(ip)
    # use timeout
    asyncore.loop(timeout)
    for sock in sock_list:
        results[sock.get_host()] = sock.get_result()
return results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can iterate over any iterable while excluding `None` values by iterating over the following generator instead:

```
>>> iterable = [1, None, 2, 3, None]
>>> iterable_nonone = (x for x in iterable if x is not None)
>>> for x in iterable_nonone:
...     print(x)
... 
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing your code, but if I understood you right, just use "is None" to check agains a None type:

```
if ping is not None:
    live.append(host)
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeError: `NoneType` object is not iterable error is raised when you try to iterate over an object whose value is equal to None.

To solve this error, make sure that any values that you try to iterate over have been assigned an iterable object, like a string or a list. Thus, if you forgot to add a `return` statement to a function it will return `None`.

However, this is not always possible. In my case, I obtained a generator from another library that contained a None at some point. So when iterating over the generator or transforming it to a list, it generated the error.

Alternatively, we can use the error inside a try and except. We can iterate through it saving the iterated elements in try until the element that gives error, at which point it will be handled by except allowing the code to continue running.

```py
save_elements = []
try:
 for i, c in enumerate(response):
    # print(i, c)
    save_elements.append(i)
except:
 pass
print(all) # values saves before the TypeError NoneType
```

`response` is a variable returned by the package to mine a social network that is full until the next paging index is empty.